# jQuery: Make a text input box selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

You know how when you open a new tab, you can start typing without having to select the search bar? I've got a text input box in HTML, and I'd like to be able to open my webpage and have that text input box immediately typeable, for lack of a better term. Say my input box looks like this:

```
 <input type="text" class="myInput" value="add an item"></input>
```

I'm using HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery right now. What code can I add to make sure the text input box is immediately typeable?

Comment: An HTML5 solution is [autofocus](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#autofocus).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `autofocus`:

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" value="add an item" autofocus/>
```

From [the input documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input):

> This Boolean attribute lets you specify that a form control should have input focus when the page loads, unless the user overrides it (e.g. by typing in a different control). Only one form element in a document can have the autofocus attribute, which is a Boolean. It cannot be applied if the type attribute is set to hidden (that is, you cannot automatically set focus to a hidden control). Note that the focusing of the control may occur before the firing of the DOMContentLoaded event.

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" value="add an item" autofocus>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_input_autofocus.asp

Answer (score 2):

in html use autofocus, in jquery use $('.myInput').focus()

Comment: The jQuery solution would select all classes of 'myInput' though, so it'd be better to add an id to the input and select that instead.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.